# C++ How can i find the vector between 2 points in a window?

Tags: c++, math

Im working on a project right now and i need to make a function that finds the vector direction for a bullet. My current code is off and i cant seem to find the reason why.

```
float AngleX = pMouse->X() - This->DirectionX();
float AngleY = pMouse->Y() - This->DirectionY();
```

Comment: I don't see how subtracting two X coordinates would give you an angle. What is `DirectionX`?

Comment: what are `DirectionX()` and `DirectionY()`? Are they components of a (possibly normalized) velocity vector? If so, remember that you want the current position, not direction of movement.

Comment: explain more, what are those variables? Tell us a story about them and what they are suppose to do. what is directionX, the current x coordinate of the this? is this a bullet? Or is DirectionX a vector or complex number, whose magnitude represents speed and whose angle represents direction?

Answer (score 6):

The best function for finding angles from (x, y) offsets is `atan2(dy, dx)`, where `dy` and `dx` are the *delta* components in each direction.

Note that the result will be in radians, and that on some graphics systems the `y` axis goes down instead of up!

The particularly nice feature of `atan2` is that it'll always give you the result in the full range of `-π .. π` which you can't get with a single `acos` or `asin` operation.  The resulting angle will be the angle of the given line relative to the positive X axis, in an anti-clockwise direction.

Comment: Also note, just for reference, a line by itself has no angle.  You need at least two line segments that touch.  The "angle" you're getting is the angle between the line connecting the two points and another imaginary line, generally one parallel to the X axis.

Comment: Good commentary, but it sounds like the OP is looking for a vector, not an angle. Of course the conversion is not hard, but you're already implicitly finding the vector. The problem seems to be that the OP can't calculate it correctly.

Comment: @jerry it's hard to tell exactly what the OP wants when his delta variables are called _AngleX_.  Some basic trig help can't hurt, though :)

Comment: @AInitak touche. My guess is it's something simple like using `this->PositionX()` and `this->PositionY()` (or whatever) instead of `this->DirectionX()` and `this->DirectionY()`.